# HTML footer at the last printed page

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I want to print my html page. I have more than 1 page and I want print my footer only at the bottom of the last page. My css

```
@page {
        size: 8.5in 11.0in;
        margin-left: 0.7cm;
        margin-top: 0.7cm;
        margin-top: 0.7cm;
        margin-bottom: 2.6cm;
        margin-right: 0.5cm
    }

#footer {
        clear: both;
        position: running(footer);
        z-index: 10;
        margin-top: -1em;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        height: 5%;
    }

 @page {
        @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer);
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<body><div id="content"></div>
       <div id="footer"></div>
<body>
```

It works, but when I have very big table in the end my content, for example 6 pages table, my  footer populates for all pages with table.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED:** Below CSS code will show footer or any content only on the last page of PDF.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">    
    @page {    
        size: A4 portrait;    
        padding-left: 8px;    
        padding-right: 0px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 150px;
    
        @bottom-center {width: 100%; content: element(footer)}
    }  
    
    @media print {
        .footer {
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            position: running(footer);
            height: 200px;
        }  
    }
</style>



<div class="footer">
    Content Here
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

To make it more simple you could position the footer within a media query for printing another way:

```
@media print { 
body {
  position: relative;
  }
#printfooter {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

As a quick work-around suggestion. Or you use css3 with the @page extension:

```
@page:last {
    @bottom-center {
        content: element(footer);
    }
}
```

For further information w3 has a pretty good documentary about [CSS Paged Media Modules](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/). 5.3, Example 7 is the information your good to go with!

Hope one of this helps! If, or if not please let me know.

Best regards,
Marian.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `:last` pseudo-class for the `@page` rule.