# Is @page:last really something?

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

I am currently working with pdf generation, and it looks like @page:last is what I need. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, and I can't find it in any doc I have found (eg. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)

But, and here is the question, I found several answers in SO talking about that mystery @page:last (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27448329/4525068 https://stackoverflow.com/a/1176839/4525068)

So, what about it? Is that been removed? Has it already existed? If not, why those answers are accepted? Any workaround?

Comment: This looks neat, they don't seem to be talking about :last here though https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/

Comment: A work around? http://www.princexml.com/forum/topic/1827/how-to-mimic-page-last-change-footer-for-last-page

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. Paged media is only supported by certain PDF generation tools, such as PrinceXML. It is not supported by any web browsers. So you can use it to make documents, and it's really handy, but not for making web sites.

Comment: You don't answer my question.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies. @page:last is not a thing. :first is a thing, and PrinceXML also supports :nth().