# how to add footer on bottom of the last printed page

Tags: css, html, pdf, printing

I am creating a web based billing system, in which I have to generate bill pdfs of multiple pages.

The problem is: I want to print the footer at the bottom of last print page.

```
#footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width:100%;
}
```

This code is printing footer on every page, but I want it only on last page.

Comment: Keep footer only at last page. Means, hide footer for other pages and display it on last page via CSS.

Comment: Try `position: absolute` and check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176770/footer-on-last-printed-page?rq=1

Comment: pdf is generated by the browser using print style sheet, how would i know which one is last page? @anu

Comment: i have tried positon:absolute, but it is giving the same result @Bellian

Comment: then please also check the link.

Comment: @HarshitKudeshiya what you are using to generate a pdf ?

Comment: only css @bhansa

Comment: Try the below solutions and links provided.

Comment: try to use JS, if it is the last page, using document.createelement()

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your stylesheet, see if it helps you:

```
@media print { 
body {
  position: relative;
  }
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Reference: [html footer at last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448199/html-footer-at-the-last-printed-page)

Comment: i have tried that, it is not working. when i add this css, footer will start overlapping the content on last print page

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @bhansa answer

```
<style>
    @media print { 
    body {
      position: relative;
      }
    #footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      }
    .empty {
        height: 150px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="content">Somebody</div>
    <div class="empty"><div>
    <div id="footer" style="height=150px; width=100%">Footer</div>
</body>
```

In order not to overlap the content, add an empty div after the content that matches the height of the footer