# position: absolute only on first page

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web programming. so basically I created a printable document and I want an element like a company's stamp to be on the bottom right corner of the last page. However when I used "position: absolute;", the element only appeared on the first page

```css
@media print{
    #non-printable { 
        display: none; 
    }
    #printable { 
        display: block;
    }
    html, body{
        height: 99%;
    }
}
.stamp {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 40px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="non-printable">
    <button onclick="print()">Print</button>
  </div>
  <div id="printable">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <div style="break-after:page;"></div>
    <h1>This is the 2nd page</h1>
    <div style="break-after:page;"></div>
    <h1>I want the element on this page</h1>
    <div class="stamp">
       <h4>BUT IT IS HERE</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68589248/5385381